# JavaX Swing. Шашки

Tags: java, swing

Всем привет! Хотел сделать игру Шашки в JavaX Swing. Сейчас использую картинку для доски шашки (пустая простая доска (черные и белые)). Вопрос: Как сделать чтобы вывести шашок в JPanel, чтобы все находились по своим местам?

Comment: Создайте класс фигур в них поле для рисунка, координаты и метод draw, который будет рисовать объект на Graphics. Если хотите более конкретного ответа выложите свой код

Comment: Дело в том , что кода еще нет только пустой класс.Не могу додуматься как вывести объекты в панель.

Comment: ну тогда начинайте делать, когда появиться проблема пишите, тут редко кто готов написать программу за вас.

Comment: если вам нужна архитектура кода (список классов и их отношения) так и напишите. Если вам надо что-то конкретное отрисовать на чем-то конкретном, тогда выложите код того, что хотите отрисовать и код того на чем хотите отрисовать.

Comment: Но все же если говорит абстрактно о каком-то JPanel, на котором надо отрисовать абстрактную фигуру в нужном месте, тогда так: В классе фигуры делате метод, который её нарисует по переданным координатам. А главном классе вызываете этот метод и передаете нужные координаты и объект Graphic на чем рисовать.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Можно унаследоваться от `Canvas` и всё рисовать на нём.